# Probelm with nested lists in python3

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

I need help to get the following data output.

```
Column: 1 Value: Value 1 Index: 0
Column: 1 Value: Value 2 Index: 1
Column: 1 Value: Value 3 Index: 2

Column: 2 Value: 1 Index: 0
Column: 2 Value: 2 Index: 1
Column: 2 Value: 3 Index: 2
```

I have 2 lists to columns and values. The index must be auto generated.

```
list_values = [["Value 1", "1"], ["Value 2", "2"], ["Value 3", "3"]]
columns = [1,2]
```

I'm trying with this code

```
for i, column in enumerate(columns):
    for values in list_values:
        for j, value in enumerate(values):
            if i == j:
                for k in range(len(list_values)):
                    print(f"Column: {column} Value: {value} Index: {k}")
```

but the output is

```
Column: 1 Value: Value 1 Index: 0
Column: 1 Value: Value 1 Index: 1
Column: 1 Value: Value 1 Index: 2
Column: 1 Value: Value 2 Index: 0
Column: 1 Value: Value 2 Index: 1
Column: 1 Value: Value 2 Index: 2
Column: 1 Value: Value 3 Index: 0
Column: 1 Value: Value 3 Index: 1
Column: 1 Value: Value 3 Index: 2
Column: 2 Value: 1 Index: 0
Column: 2 Value: 1 Index: 1
Column: 2 Value: 1 Index: 2
Column: 2 Value: 2 Index: 0
Column: 2 Value: 2 Index: 1
Column: 2 Value: 2 Index: 2
Column: 2 Value: 3 Index: 0
Column: 2 Value: 3 Index: 1
Column: 2 Value: 3 Index: 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just one nested loop works:

```
for column in columns:
    for i, pair in enumerate(list_values):
        print(f"Column: {column} Value: {pair[column-1]} Index: {i}")
    print()
```